# Joomla 1.5 - Creating SQL tables in components

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

Joomla 1.5 has JTable, which can be extended to act as an Active Record system (Create/Read/Update/Delete).

However, I can not find any way for this interface to create the table represented by my JTable sub-class.

Every example I have found has started with "manually create the database tables... ", then created a JTable class to work with it. I would like to be able to distribute my plugin and have it create the tables on setup, so that this is not necessary.

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done in the *[install.sql](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_3_-_Using_the_Database#Creating_the_Installation_SQL_File)* of your extension (The link is related to component but I guess for plugins it's the same).